# Помогите разобраться с массивом php

Tags: php, javascript, массивы, pdo, csv

Я загружаю csv файл такого вида

"Product 1",-7,WH1

"Product 3",2,WH2

"Product 3",20,WH3

"Product 1",1,WH1

После парсинга csv файла массив приобретает такой вид

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product 1
            [1] => -7
            [2] => WH1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product 3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => WH2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product 3
            [1] => 20
            [2] => WH3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => WH1
        )

)
```

мне нужно, что если продукты одинаковые,
то суммировать их количество

Comment: "одинаковые продукты" - это у которых имя одинаковое? или эти WH1, WH2 и т.д.? В любом случае, что мешает создать новый массив и вносить в него нужные данные? Т.е. если такой продукт уже есть (можно в качестве ключа использовать его имя, тогда быстро определите наличие/отсутствие продукта), то обновляете данные, если продукта еще нет - добавляете данные

Comment: @gudfar, а как парсите?

Comment: имена одинаковые

Comment: @Grundy, судя по всему через fgetcsv, т.е. придется по массиву еще раз пробежаться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать на этапе разбора данных файла, если вы используете fgetcsv(), а не, например, str_getcsv()

```
<?php
$output = [];
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if(isset($output[$data[0]])){
                $output[$data[0]][1] += $data[1];
            } else {
                $output[$data[0]] = $data;
            }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [Product 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product 1
            [1] => -6
            [2] => WH1
        )

    [Product 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product 3
            [1] => 22
            [2] => WH2
        )

)
```

Comment: блин, реально все просто